# solving tridiagonal system with non-zero opposite corners in python efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I want to solve the system A.b=x where A is ***almost*** a tridiagonal matrix in python:

A is a matrix like this

```
a b 0 0 .... 0 0 b
b a b 0 .... 0 0 0
0 b a b .... 0 0 0
.
.
0 0 0 0 .... b a b
b 0 0 0 .... 0 b a
```

i.e. tridiagonal with non-zero opposite corners.

I can solve and integrate my system using the numpy solver:

```
numpy.linalg.solve
```

This works but is terribly slow as my matrices are massive and I don't think it takes advantage of the sparseness and near tri-diagonality of the A array.

If it were a pure tridiagonal system, I know how to quickly and efficiently solve it using the classic forwards and backwards substitution algorithm, but I am stumped with those non-zero opposite corners.  I looked through numpy and scipy, and the only thing I could think of was to try and convert the NxN matrix into a banded system and try to use solve_banded from scipy:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.html

Am I missing something obvious, is there a trick to solve this system efficiently with an in-built function of python numpy or scipy packages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is circulant system and it can be solved with FFT in O(N log N). See [scipy.linalg.solve_circulant](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_circulant.html).

I do not know what massive means but I guess it is about 100000, otherwise one will likely run out of RAM. Below there is code for slightly smaller case of N=10000.

```
import scipy.linalg
import numpy as np
from time import time

N = 10000
a, b = 1, 2
y = np.random.uniform(size=N)

# make big matrix
M = np.zeros((N,N))
np.fill_diagonal(M, a)
np.fill_diagonal(M[1:,:], b)
np.fill_diagonal(M[:,1:], b)
M[-1, 0] = M[0, -1] = b

tic = time()
x0 = np.linalg.solve(M, y)
toc = time()
print("np.linalg.solve", toc - tic)

tic = time()
# just use first row
x1 = scipy.linalg.solve_circulant(M[0], y)
toc = time()

print("scipy.linalg.solve_circulant", toc - tic)
print(np.isclose(x0, x1).all())
```

And the result is:

```
np.linalg.solve 7.422604322433472
scipy.linalg.solve_circulant 0.0010323524475097656
True
```

Speedup is indeed significant.